# Верно ли словосочетание "жемчужина отдыха"?

Tags: фразеология, стилистика, словосочетания

Подскажите, верно ли словосочетание "жемчужина отдыха"? Например, жемчужина пляжного отдыха.
Жемчужина Египта может быть, а вот отдыха, даже не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Надо задаться вопросом, каков контекст и что там подразумевается под словом *отдых*. Скорее всего, имеется в виду место отдыха или программа отдыха. Если это ясно из контекста, то скрипя сердце "жемчужину отдыха" можно принять как некий разговорный вариант. Хотя гораздо лучше сказать "жемчужина нашей зоны отдыха" или "жемчужина нашей программы отдыха".

Пляжный отдых — это не конкретное место и не конкретная программа, это вид отдыха, нечто обстрактное, к которому жемчужина не "клеится". Но может быть, например, такое: "Жемчужиной любого пляжного отдыха является купание в полнолуние с бегемотами". Смысл здесь таков: жемчужиной любой программы пляжного отдыха является... Это уже имеет смысл.

Answer (score 0):

**Пляжный отдых** –  это  не просто отдых на пляже, а вполне **конкретное понятие** (пляжи, инфраструктура, развлечения и т.д.)

**Окинава – настоящая жемчужина пляжного отдыха Японии!** 
http://tabitabi.ru/article/beaches_in_okinawa.html

Пляжный отдых – самое популярное направление в туризме. Название говорит само за себя – отдых на побережье водоема (озера, моря, океана), в основном – спокойный и пассивный, предназначенный для восстановления сил и релаксации.

[http://womanwiki.ru/w/Пляжный_отдых](http://womanwiki.ru/w/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: В статье по первой ссылке даже "дайвинг — настоящая жемчужина...". Я привык доверять Вашему чувству языка, но здесь у меня непреодолимый барьер :)

Comment: Неверно так формулировать: "Окинава – часть пляжного отдыха Японии", поэтому неверно и такое: "Окинава – жемчужина пляжного отдыха Японии"

Comment: @grizzly Дайвинг как событие может быть жемчужиной вашей программы отдыха.

Comment: @М_Г Там это жемчужина какой-то территории. (Это нужно было уточнить; спасибо, что поправили.)

Comment: @grizzly Нонсенс: вид спорта — это жемчужина территории(?!). Чтобы утверждать, что А — это жемчужина Б, нужно хотя бы, чтобы А было частью (принадлежало) Б.

Comment: Я же не статью вам предлагаю читать, а только выражение "жемчужина пляжного отдыха". Пляжный отдых  (по набору комфорта и услуг) можно оценить по какой-нибудь системе, например как отель (три звездочки, пять звездочек). Вот на Окинаве много первоклассных мест для пляжного отдыха, поэтому она жемчужина пляжного отдыха (= жемчужина с точки зрения пляжного отдыха).

Comment: @Jasmin Но Вашу ссылку на статью я понял как ссылку на авторитетный источник. Ладно, оставим это. Мне кажется, что Ваш пример не так сильно режет слух только потому, что он воспринимается как "Окинава — жемчужина Японии (в смысле пляжного отдыха)". Поэтому явная ошибка становится менее явной.

Comment: У меня всего два авторитетных источника - Розенталь и ПАС,  за остальные я не отвечаю. Теперь о жемчужине. Ошибка ли это? Сравните: Окинава - прекрасное  место  для пляжного отдыха. Место (какое?) - для отдыха (определение выражено родительным падежом с предлогом). Место (какое) отдыха (определение выражено родительным падежом без предлога).  Также: дом для отдыха - дом отдыха.  Отсюда: Окинава - прекрасное  место  (жемчужина) пляжного отдыха.